# interfaces classes in c# in Model class(MVC)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, interface

Could you please help me in the below code whether the interface and classes are structured appropriately?

I mean to say, I need to have single method in the interface which is loaddata(), 
but I have 2 different methods( returns lists), to cater 2 different tables.

Classes EmployeeDetails and JobDetails are the readonly classes, and  the data comes to this from external database.

```
public interface IGetData
{
  public List<EmployeeDetails> LoadData{get;set;}
  public List<JobDetails> LoadData2{get;set;}
}

public  class EmployeeDetails : IGetData
{             
  public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
  public string EmployeePosition { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeDivision { get; set; }
  public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
  public string ApproverName { get; set; }
  public int ApproverID { get; set; }

  public EmployeeDetails()
  {
    public string LoggedInEmployeeName
    {
      get
      { 
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
      }
    }

    STASEntities STASContext = new STASEntities();

    public  List<EmployeeDetails> LoadData
    { 
      get
      {
        var EmployeeResults = from e in STASContext.Employee_VIEW
                              where
                              e.UserName == LoggedInEmployeeName 
                              select new EmployeeDetails
                              {
                                EmployeeDivision    = e.BusinessUnitName,
                                EmployeeID          = e.EmployeeId,
                                EmployeePosition    = " ",
                                EmployeeName        = e.EmployeeName,
                                ApproverID          =   e.EmpAppId,
                                ApproverName        =  e.ApproverName,
                                EmployeeNumber      = e.EmployeeNumber
                              };
        return EmployeeResults.ToList();  
      }
    }
  }
}

public class JobDetails:EmployeeDetails, IGetData//for future employee assigned against job.
{
  //  public IList<ContractDetails_View> JobNameList { get; set; }
  public int ContractID { get; set; }
  public string JobName { get; set; }
  public JobDetails() {
  public  List<JobDetails> LoadData2
  { 
    get
    {
      var jobResult = from c in STASContext.ContractDetails_View 
                      select new JobDetails
                      {                    
                        JobName=c.JobName,
                         ContractID = c.ContractId
                      };

      return jobResult.ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Format your code, ask a real question (clearify your problem). Be as clear as possible.

Comment: I couldn't understand the question...can you please be specific while asking a question? it will help others to answer it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your code, this is going to be a little bit more of a guess.  But your interface looks wrong.  It looks wrong because the EmplyeeeDetails class doesn't call the LoadData2 function, and JobDetails doesn't call the LoadData function.

It looks like you should have two separate interfaces (and they look more like functions that properties):

```
public interface IGetEmployeeDetails
{
  List<EmployeeDetails> LoadEmployeeDetails();
}

public interface IGetJobDetails
{
  List<JobDetails> LoadJobDetails();
}
```

And then implement them separately:

```
public  class EmployeeDetails : IGetEmployeeDetails
{
  //class stuff
}

public class JobDetails : EmployeeDetails, IGetJobDetails
{
  //class stuff
}
```

Because JobDetails inherits EmployeeDetails AND implements IGetJobDetails, it will have available to it both interface calls, `LoadEmployeeDetails()` and `LoadJobDetails()`.

You might be able to replace both interfaces with a generic version:

```
public interface IGetDetails<T> {
  List<T> LoadData();
}
```

Other than that, you would need to specify what the actual problem is.

Comment: thanks very much. I have implemented the code as mentioned and it works fine.